# Marcus, Chapter 3, Exercise 35(d)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K \subset L$ be number fields with rings of integers $R \subset S$. Suppose that $L = K(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in S$. Let $f$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$, and write $$f(X) = (X-\alpha)g(X) \qquad \text{where} \qquad g(X) = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 X + \cdots + \gamma_{n-1} X^{n-1}$$
($n=[L:K]$ and $\gamma_i \in L$).

> Show that the $R$-module generated by $\gamma_0, \cdots, \gamma_{n-1}$ is $R[\alpha]$.

I'm not sure about the inclusion $R[\alpha] \subseteq \sum R \gamma_i$. Here is what I have so far. $\alpha$ is assumed to be in $S$, so the coefficients of $f$ are in $R$. Expanding $(X-\alpha)g(X)$ (per the hint) and noting that $\gamma_{n-1} =1$ gives us $\gamma_i \in R[\alpha]$ and $\alpha \in \sum R\gamma_i$. We also have $R = R\gamma_{n-1} \subseteq \sum R \gamma_i$. So if we show that $\sum R \gamma_i$ forms a ring, or that the higher powers of $\alpha$ are in $\sum R\gamma_i$, then we're done. Do you have any hints on how to proceed?

Here is the full #35 (up to (d)). I'm not sure how relevant the previous parts are. Part (c) + #34(a) does show that $\sum R\gamma_i$ is a direct sum.

[image]